# How can I cut these faces in this direction and make vertex along the way?

Tags: modeling

There should be one vertex in each of these curved faces. Don't know how to explain it better, sorry, I hope the red line speaks for itself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if I understand correctly what you ask, you can do it with the knife (K to activate, C to cut vertically)

Comment: I've just edited the question and added another picture. See if it is better.

Comment: it looks like you have 2 separate meshes, which makes things a bit more complicated, you could use a knife for the vertical line, then create a vertex on the edge of the other mesh and make it stick to the other mesh? please give more precisions or even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/